# Documents and Media file view link

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

Is there a way to obtain an URL to open document in Documents and media portlet? Not to directly download it, but to open a document view. E.g. I have got a DLFileEntry object in my potrlet, after clicking a view href link, it opens a view of this entry in Documents and Media portlet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creation of the URL to see my stored file from another portlet can be implemented like this. Leaving it here for further use.

```
    public Map<String, String> fileViewUrl(List<DLFileEntry> entries,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, String> urls = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (DLFileEntry fileEntry : entries) {

        PortletURL myUrl = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request, "20",
                themeDisplay.getPlid(), PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
        try {
            myUrl.setWindowState(WindowState.NORMAL);
        } catch (WindowStateException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            myUrl.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW);
        } catch (PortletModeException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(myUrl.toString());
        sb.append("&_20_struts_action=%2Fdocument_library%2Fview_file_entry&_20_fileEntryId=");
        sb.append(fileEntry.getFileEntryId());
        urls.put(fileEntry.getTitle(), sb.toString());
    }

    return urls;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like preview file entry you should use this: [DLUtil.getPreviewURL](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/util/DLUtil.html#getPreviewURL%28com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileEntry,%20com.liferay.portal.kernel.repository.model.FileVersion,%20com.liferay.portal.theme.ThemeDisplay,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean%29).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think this is a link to preview document as a download , however I just wanted to open my document in Documents and Media portlet.